# Colored text block to be populated programmatically

Tags: wpf, textarea

I want to have the functional equivalent of a text block that supports multiple colors.

I've tried creating a UserControl and adding multiple text blocks and setting their foreground to the colors I need, however this is really slow as I will be changing and clearing the text every few seconds.

I've also tried using a RichTextBox, but it seems like it was not designed to be populated programmatically.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TextBlock` can display multiple "runs" - blocks of text with same formatting. Use `Inlines` property to access them:

```
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Media;

var inlines = textBlock.Inlines;
inlines.Add(new Run("This is red") { Foreground = Brushes.Red });
inlines.Add(new LineBreak()); // in case if you want new line
inlines.Add(new Run("And this is blue") { Foreground = Brushes.Blue });
```

Comment: I love you. (At first this wasn't working for me, but I had accidentally removed the InitializeComponent() in the constructor.)